# Are these coffee beans unroasted?

Tags: coffee, beans

I bought these coffee beans in Bali. I tried to grind them up to make a cup of coffee this morning, but they didn't grind properly, leaving lots of big chunks. It was more like grinding peanuts than coffee. The coffee didn't taste or smell anything like coffee either, and it was a really weak brown colour.

I'm assuming that I've gone and bought unroasted beans (although it didn't say anything about that on the pack). Is this the case?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Yes, they are not roasted. I think you can do this in a normal oven, but I have never done it myself so I cannot advice you on temperatures etc.

Comment: The Basics of Home Roasting: http://www.breworganic.com/coffee/howtoroast.htm

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured. I've thrown a few in a pan to cook for a while and I'll see how it comes out.

Answer (score 4):

you can also roast them in a hot-air popcorn popper, which you can easily pick up at a thrift store or garage sale for a few bucks. more info is here: http://www.sweetmarias.com/airpop/airpopmethod.php

i have roasted coffee this way for years, and it is indeed easy, and much cheaper! it's a bit messy, though, because the chaff from the roasting process blows around, so i do it outside in the summer. in the winter, i take a vacation from home-roasting and buy from a local roaster, and i count my pennies for a small roasting machine. ; )

Comment: Due to the ridiculously long winter we've had this year, I couldn't take the wait and decided to find a way to roast with my popper even while cold outside. I found a way to do it: put your popper in a cardboard box and, if necessary, close one or more of the flaps. Since the popper pulls in air from the bottom (at least, mine does) it will get warm air and be able to roast the coffee just like when doing it in the summer.

Comment: that's a great tip, Michael! i have resorted to roasting in my garage, but it takes a long time when it's cold for my poppers (yes, i have two i use, actually) to warm up to the roasting temperature. this might help, though -- i'll have to remember to try it.